# AngularJS Change DOM based on Session

Tags: angularjs, dom

I'm writing a SPA that has a login form. The app has a sidebar on the left which I do not want to be shown unless the user is authenticated.

I have a service that handles authentication:
 login/logff methods use $cookieStore to store a flag in session to store user's authenticated state.
 isAuthenticated retrieves from $cookieStore and returns true/false

So my login form does login but in order to see the sidebar, I have to do a page refresh.

All of this is wrapped in a shell.html container from that I used for layout.  In that form there is a line of html like so:

```
<div data-ng-include="'/app/layout/sidebar.html'" ng-if="vm.authenticated == true"></div>
```

In the shell.js I have code as follows to check the authService and set that value.

```
vm.authenticated = checkAuth();
function checkAuth() {
   return authService.isAuthenticated();
```

}

It works as far as that goes, because when I do the page refresh, the sidebar does indeed disappear.

What I'm lost on is how to get this appear/disappear for the sidebar to happen without a page refresh.

Am I just barking up the wrong tree?  Is there a better way architect the application than what I'm doing?

I have started looking into using $watch for this but I'm not sure if that's the right way to go either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is what did the trick for me.  Thanks to Clais for the guidance!

```
vm.authenticated = function () {
        return authService.isAuthenticated();
    }
```

Comment: you are halfway there with this implementation.  The other half is that once the user has logged in, you need to change the value of `vm.authenticated` within that function.

Comment: vm.authenticated is being set to the return value of that function.  Or at least that was my intent.  Do I have that written incorrectly?

Comment: no, my comment probably wasn't clear.  You need to change the value of `vm.authenticated` from inside your authentication function after the authentication is successful.  the `checkAuth()` function is only a single fired event, it's not continually running that function to see if the result is different, whereas the `vm.authenticated` property itself can be continually monitored for change.  therefore, you need to force the value to be updated.

Comment: Thanks I see what you mean now and it worked.  Whew!  Thanks for being awesome!

Comment: right, I was thinking that you could just bypass that extra function definition and it would work but I wasn't 100% sure... I'm glad that got you thinking and you tried it :)